# Return only diagonal values (zero in the other cells) in one matrix to another matrix with same dimensions

Tags: excel, vba, matrix, covariance

I have to shrink values in the variance-covariance matrix towards the variance (diagonal values in matrix) by a shrinkage factor (lambda), so:
lambda*shrinkagematrix+(1-lambda)*variancecovariancematrix, where:

Variance covariance matrix is:

```
Function VarCovar(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim numcols As Integer

    numcols = rng.Columns.Count
    numrows = rng.Rows.Count

    Dim matrix() As Double
    ReDim matrix(numcols - 1, numcols - 1)

    For i = 1 To numcols
        For j = 1 To numcols
            matrix(i - 1, j - 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Covar(rng.Columns(i), rng.Columns(j)) * numrows / (numrows - 1)
        Next j
    Next i
    VarCovar = matrix
```

, this gives me a matrix that looks for example like this:

```
 0.40  -0.10  0.11                                                 
-0.10   0.17 -0.03                                              
 0.11  -0.03  0.19
```

Then I have trouble creating the Shrinkage matrix which should look like:

```
0.40  0.00  0.00                                      
0.00  0.17  0.00                                              
0.00  0.00  0.19
```

i.e returning ONLY diagonal values (= variances of the variables) and zero in all other cells.

So in some kind of way, making it return a matrix containing only the values for when row=column number, i.e.
(1,1), (2,2) and (3,3) values.

Anyone that can help with this?

Comment: isn't it easier if inside your loop you'd have an if stating if i = <>j then .value = 0

Comment: @Jo.lass why so complicated? Just drop the `j` loop and replace `j` with `i`.

Comment: @Jo.lass where would you put that if statement in the coding?

Comment: @Pernille don't do that, that will make your code slow. I fixed my answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only one loop that counts from `i = 1 to 3` to fill `Matrix(1, 1)`, `Matrix(2, 2)` and `Matrix(3, 3)` using `Matrix(i, i)`

```
Function VarCovar(InputMatix As Range) As Variant
    Dim MatrixColumns  As Long
    MatrixColumns = InputMatix.Columns.Count

    Dim MatrixRows  As Long
    MatrixRows = InputMatix.Rows.Count

    Dim Matrix() As Double
    ReDim Matrix(1 To MatrixColumns, 1 To MatrixColumns)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To MatrixColumns
        Matrix(i, i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Covar(InputMatix.Columns(i), InputMatix.Columns(i)) * MatrixRows / (MatrixRows - 1)
    Next i

    VarCovar = Matrix
End Function
```

Note that I changed the `Matrix` dimenstions `Matrix(1 To MatrixDimension, 1 To MatrixDimension)` to start with `1` and not `0` so you can easily use it to write it to cells:

```
Sub test()

    Range("A5:C7").Value = VarCovar(Range("A1:C3"))

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

I'm still having issues with it (sorry I'm totally new to VBA and not completely understanding all the coding)

I have this area, let's say A3:F27, which has returns for the different variables (6 variables with 24 observations each).

The function you just wrote is not working as:
VarCovar(A3:F27) since it comes with the message "not symetric matrix".

Then I tried renaming your function to "VarCovarZeros", and tried:
VarCovarZeros(VarCovar(A3:F27)) 
Where VarCovar is "my" original function.

This returns #VALUE! , i.e. not working. How can i change it?

Comment: I need to transform the "Raw data" into a matrix that only gives the variances in the diagonal and zeros elsewhere, OR transform "my" VarCovar matrix into a matrix that has the (1,1), (2,2), (3,3) ... etc. values in it and zeros elsewhere. 

Does it make sense?

Comment: @Pernille Ah, I think I got it. I changed my answer, please try again.